# Returning useable values from ConfigParse

Tags: python

Using the code described bellow, i can sucessfully retrieve the properties stored into the file.cfg, but how can i use the output into others variables?

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

class Main:

   def get_properties(self, section, *variables):
        cfgFile = 'c:\file.cfg'
        parser = SafeConfigParser()
        parser.read(cfgFile)
        properties= variables
        return {
            variable : parser.get(section,variable) for variable in properties

        }

   def run_me(self):
        config_vars= self.get_properties('database','host','dbname')
        print config_vars

op=Main()
op.run_me()
```

Im still learning Python, but i'm not sure what i need to do to set the output into individual variables:

current output:

```
{'host': 'localhost', 'dbname': 'sample'}
```

what i would like to have:

```
db_host = localhost
db_name = sample
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def run_me(self):
     config_vars= self.get_properties('database','host','dbname')
     for key, value in config_vars.items():
         print key, "=", value
```

You recieved dict-object `config_vars`, so your can using config variables as values of the dict:

```
 >>> print config_vars["dbname"]
 sample
 >>> print config_vars["host"]
 localhost
```

Read more about python dictionaries in [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: Accepting your answer in 7 minutes.  Thanks for the direct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach:

```
import ConfigParser
import inspect

class DBConfig:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.dbname = None

    def foo(self): pass

class ConfigProvider:
    def __init__(self, cfg):
        self.cfg = cfg

    def update(self, section, cfg):
        for name, value in inspect.getmembers(cfg):
            if name[0:2] == '__' or inspect.ismethod(value):
                continue

            #print name
            if self.cfg.has_option(section, name):
                setattr(cfg, name, self.cfg.get(section, name))

class Main:
    def __init__(self, dbConfig):
        self.dbConfig = dbConfig

    def run_me(self):
        print('Connecting to %s:%s...' % (self.dbConfig.host, self.dbConfig.dbname))


config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.add_section('Demo')
#config.set('Demo', 'host', 'domain.com')
config.set('Demo', 'dbname', 'sample')

configProvider = ConfigProvider(config)

dbConfig = DBConfig()
configProvider.update('Demo', dbConfig)

main = Main(dbConfig)
main.run_me()
```

The idea is that you collect all important properties in a class (where you can also set the defaults).

The method `ConfigProvider.update()` will then overwrite those with the values from the config (if they exist).

This allows you to access properties with the simple `obj.name` syntax.

[gist](https://gist.github.com/3871952)

Comment: Thank you  for the info, i will keep this for future reference.